# How do I convert JSON object to CLLOCATIONDEGREES?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I convert JSON object to CLLocationDegrees?

```
 if let value = response.result.value {

      let json = JSON(value)

      for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

            let lat = subJson["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
            let lng = subJson["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees // This will return error



       }

  }
```

The data type for JSON is

```
{
  "latitude": 2323.44555,
  "longitude": 2313.344555
}
```

It just won't work

Comment: What error is returned exactly?

Comment: @Larme `Cast from JSON to unrelated object CLLocationDegrees (aka Double) always fail` then the app crashes

Comment: Typo `longitude` vs `longtitude` ?

Comment: JSON cannot transport CLLocationDegrees. Your subJson["latitude"] is probably a String, absolutely not a CLLocationDegrees. And you can't magically transform a String to a CLLocationDegrees just by saying "Do it" to the compiler...

Comment: @sinusGob Are you using SwiftyJSON library for parsing?

Comment: @Moritz `subJson["latitude"]` is a JSON, I checked it using `type(of: object)`

Comment: @Imad Yeah Im using SwiftyJSON for parsing.

Comment: @Moritz do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message

> Cast from JSON to unrelated object CLLocationDegrees (aka Double) always fails

is pretty clear, subscripted `JSON` in the `SwiftyJSON` library returns `JSON`. You have to get the `doubleValue` (`CLLocationDegrees` is a type alias of `Double`)

```
for (key,subJson) in json { // don't annotate types unless the compiler tells you
        let lat = subJson["latitude"].doubleValue
        let lng = subJson["longitude"].doubleValue
        // do something with lat and lng
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get it

```
let json = [
    "latitude": 2323.44555,
    "longitude": 2313.344555
]
var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
if let lat = json["latitude"] as? Double,let lng = json["longitude"] as? Double {
        location.latitude = lat
        location.longitude = lng
}
```